# Putting into words variable transformation

Tags: random-variable, cumulative-distribution-function, variable

If Y is a random variable which comes from a transformation of X : $ Y = \phi(X) $, the formula for the tranformation of this random variable can be written as follows :
$$
F_Y(y) = P(Y \leq y) = P(X \leq \phi^{-1}(y) ) = F_X(\phi^{-1}(y) )
$$
I am able to understand mathematically each of these equalities but I fail to put words behind it.

This is how I would put it : "The cdf of the random variable Y, with Y being a transformation phi of the random variable X, is equal to the cdf of X applied to the reverse of the phi transformation applied to Y".

However, I think that this formulation is messy and unclear. Could you come up with a better one ?

Comment: Note that your formula is true when $\phi$ is increasing and invertible but wouldn't hold for e.g. $\phi(x) = -x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CDF on $Y$ for the transformed $x$ is equal to the CDF on $X$ for the de-transformed $y$.